# display a comment on action links

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

How to display a comment when the user mouse is over an action link? I'm using a gridview and here is one of my columns that contains an action link :

```
grid.Column(header: "", format:  (item) => Html.ActionLink("Détails", "Details",
 new { id = item.id_projet}, new { @class = "details" }), style: "actions")
```

Comment: Can you add a title to the link? If so, browsers will display the comment as a tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a title?

```
grid.Column(header: "", format:  (item) => Html.ActionLink("Détails", "Details",
 new { id = item.id_projet}, new { @class = "details", @title = "text here" }),
 style: "actions")
```

This will display the text `text here` if you hover the link.